# How to create a LINQ to Entities query including both tag class name and text string

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, asp.net-mvc-4

My ASP.NET MVC project has some

> chapter class

and related

> tag class

They have many to many relationship though one tag has multiple chapter and also one chapter has multiple tags on it.

My question is: I want to make a query by using `tag.title` within this structure but LINQ doesn't allow objects; it only gets variables like `string`, `int` ...etc.

I am feeling a little bit stupid but I can't figured it out this basic thing :( (May be I have to give a break to let it be clear in my mind)

My models are:

```
public partial class Chapter
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public partial class Tag
{
    public int? TagId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CallCount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}
```

and also for db:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

so here we go:

```
var tag = (from t in db.Tags where t.Title.Contains(search_word)).FirstOrDefault();
var chapters = (from c in db.Chapters where (m.Title.Contains(search_word) || m.Tags.Contains(tag)) select c).ToList();
```

As I explained above; it gives

> "you should use string, guid, int... on queries"

error for this query. I think there is a logical failure I made but my brain stopped responding...

Briefly; I want to search by tag names and if you have another approach I will be pleased to listen it..

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The error is in the first, second or both queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
var tag = (from t in db.Tags 
           where t.Title.Contains(search_word)
           select t).FirstOrDefault();
var chapters = (from c in db.Chapters 
                where m.Title.Contains(search_word) 
                    || m.Tags.Any(t => t.TagId == tag.TagId)
                select c).ToList();
```